# laravel blade form not routing to a named route

Tags: html, laravel, forms, laravel-5

I am new to named routing in Laravel 5.5 and I am facing a strange thing while trying to perform an action of a form;

**Setups and Explanations:**

I set up my routes in web.php

```
Route::post('questions/save_bulk', 'QuestionsController@save_bulk')->name('save_bulk');
Route::post('questions/store_bulk', 'QuestionsController@store_bulk')->name('store_bulk');
```

Then I set up `store_bulk` and `save_bulk` in `QuestionsController`:

```
public function store_bulk(Request $request)
{
    //$x = some DB::selects statements;
    return view('questions.store_bulk', ['x'=> $x]);
}

public function save_bulk(Request $request){
    dd($request);
}
```

And finally this is my blade form in `questions.store_bulk` which should lead to `QuestionsController.save_bulk`:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('save_bulk')}}">
        {{csrf_field()}}

        /* some codes and input fields */

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
        </div>

</form>
```

**Problem**

The problem is that when I submit this form, instead of taking me to the desired route and perform `dd($request)`, it is just refreshing the page without the inputs I had as if Laravel took the last post form which returned the view `questions.store_bulk`.
Though this is the exact same way I used to get into the view `questions.store_bulk` in the first place, a strange thing occurs:  when I try to inspect elements in the blade page I get the following:

```
<form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/store_bulk">

/* some codes and inputs */

</form>
```

in the codes the route should go to `QuestionsController.save_bulk` but when inspecting the HTML it says it goes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/store_bulk`, and if I inspect and change the route manually inside the HTML and write `http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/save_bulk` it goes to the right route and perform `dd($request)`.

**Question**

Why is this happening? am I missing something?

**Note**

I am using Laravel 5.5 locally on my PC preparing a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar issues with routing.. You can change the url.. e.g. questions/somethingelse/save_bulk.. so the urls won't clash.. Or run php artisan cache:clear or view:clear incase you implemented a page caching system

Comment: I am not using the same names anywhere for anything to clash though.. it's like either questions/store_bulk, or questions/save_bulk.. and the first one is working properly while the second one isn't not even while inspecting the page. and each one is routing to a different named route.. so where could the clash come from?

Comment: clearing the cache and view were enough to solve this, yet I still couldn't understand why this happened. I would be more than happy if you can elaborate :)